# Javascript/jQuery Drag and Drop Limit parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, limit

got the following problem. 
 i need the following just to be drag/dropable in the green area.

should be something like that:

```
limit($(this).parent());
```

but thats not working, im using this for dnd:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
drag: function () {

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
    var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
    $('#posX').val('x: ' + xPos);
    $('#posY').val('y: ' + yPos);
},
stop: function (event, ui) {

    // Show dropped position.
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
    var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
    $('#posX').val('x: ' + left);
    $('#posY').val('y: ' + top);
}
```

});

hope someone can help me with that ;) thx so far

http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1850/

///////////////
Update - getting correct x/y Position and just allow inside green area: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1858/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`containment`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option for this which constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region.:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = Math.abs(offset.left);
        var yPos = Math.abs(offset.top);
        $('#posX').val('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').val('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        var left = Math.abs(Stoppos.left);
        var top = Math.abs(Stoppos.top);
        $('#posX').val('x: ' + left);
        $('#posY').val('y: ' + top);
        $('#info').val('x: ' + left + ' y: ' + top);
    },
    containment: $("#content")
});
```

### [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1852/)

Comment: Ahhh nice thx, i was looking for that but couldnt found...
and how can i set x and y value to `#content`so that green area left upper corner is x:0 y:0

Comment: i tryed this, but its only working with padding if i try to set margin-top/leftto my #content it wont show correct data http://jsfiddle.net/DGbT3/1854/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the position according to its parent then use `.position()`, then check if the `xPos` and `yPos` are bigger than 0 and smaller that its parent's width..

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).position();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').val('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').val('y: ' + yPos);
        if(xPos < 0 || xPos > $(this).parent().width())
            console.log("outside");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // Show dropped position.
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        var left = Stoppos.left;
        var top = Stoppos.top;
        $('#posX').val('left: ' + left);
        $('#posY').val('top: ' + top);
        if(xPos < 0 || xPos > $(this).parent().width())
            console.log("outside");
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: there is a typo in your `#content` css `position`..

Comment: ill try to work with this to get correct x y coordinates